# JUnit testing in Android - DialogFragment

Tags: android, junit, android-fragments

I have a button in a FragmentActivity which, when pressed should open a DialogFragment.

I want to test that it works using JUnit for Android in Eclipse.

With an Activity I could use ActivityMonitor. How can I test that the correct Fragment has opened when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are opening your dialog fragment sort of like this:

```
DialogFragment dlg = YourDialogFragment.newInstance(..);
dlg.show(getFragmentManager(), "yourDialogTag");
```

you can check that it's up & showing by doing this in your test case:

```
// Click stuff on the UI-thread
getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
Fragment dialog = getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("yourDialogTag");
assertTrue(dialog instanceof DialogFragment);
assertTrue(((DialogFragment) dialog).getShowsDialog());
```

Comment: Make sure to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` if you are using the support library's DialogFragment.

Comment: This is not correct. getShowsDialog() tells you whether this fragment should be shown in a dialog. It does not tell you IF it is currently being shown. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#getShowsDialog()